# Devise issue I think, 500 internal server error on SessionController#new as HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

I am working with a Ruby on Rails program previously developed by someone else and it uses Devise.  I just did a new whole Ruby on Rails setup on a MAC mini.  When I run locahost:300 it routes to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in and fails with below:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2022-03-10 09:17:55 -0500
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Pluck (3.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by Users::SessionsController#new as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 33ms (ActiveRecord: 6.1ms | Allocations: 39224)

fatal (exception reentered):
```

So nothing to really go on here - tried updating gems ect, but nothing changes.
Here is the gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
 "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 7.0.0'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: 
https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'


# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development 

# Font Awesome Icons
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.0.13'

# User Roles and permissions
gem 'devise', '~> 4.6', '>= 4.6.1'
gem 'devise_invitable', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.6'
gem 'pundit'
gem 'rolify'

# Image uploading
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.0'
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.3'
gem 'fog-aws'
gem 'remotipart', '~> 1.2'

# Nested Forms
gem "cocoon"

# Text Editor
gem 'ckeditor'

# CLI for rake tasks
gem 'highline'

# Friendly Time Display
gem 'local_time'

# Record Duplicaiton
gem 'amoeba'

# For ordering of lists
gem 'acts_as_list'

# For Scheduling Cron Jobs
gem 'whenever', require: false

# For App Settings
gem "rails-settings-cached"

# For PDF Generation
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge', '~> 0.12.5.1'

# Inline editing
gem "best_in_place", git: "https://github.com/mmotherwell/best_in_place"

# HTTP Calls
gem 'rest-client'

# Charts
gem 'chart-js-rails'

# toastr

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger 
console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'rails_real_favicon'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

I am new to Ruby and Rails, so I also am not sure how you can debug these things here, especially since this startup is all controlled by Devise, I have no way to tell anything.

Thanks for any input in advance and let me know if you need to see anything else on the project setup.

Comment: Did you follow all the setup steps they include in their readme? https://github.com/heartcombo/devise

Comment: @Mark I did not set it up originally but as far as I can tell the answer is yes.  It was working on another machine previously, but on this machine, everything was installed and updated, now it does not work.  The database is connectecd so I am not sure from ther readme if there is other setup Devise requires.  I don't think so since the project was copy before many times.

Comment: could you check if log level is set to debug and is it really "fatal (exception reentered):" the end of the stack trace? if there's more please post the logs

Comment: @AndreDurao thanks for the response.  Yes checked the log level and it is set as config.log_level = :debug in the application.rb.  And yes the very last line I see in the terminal is fatal (exception reentered):